# iOS8/Swift: Facebook SDK: Login with Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift

I correctly implemented the Login Button and everything works fine.

Only thing is that I just want to use it so people can do the register process with their facebook data in one click and then I wanna use the facebook data (name, email) to perform an account creation REST call to my API.

That also works perfectly fine - but I (wrongly) implemented it listening to the two Delegate Methods listening for response from the OAuth Process:

```
func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
            println("user logged in!")
            self.showLoadingOverlay()
        }

func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser){
            let mail = user.objectForKey("email") as String
            println("User Email: \(mail)")
            self.eMail = mail
            self.firstName = user.first_name
            self.lastName = user.last_name
            self.pW = "123456"
            registerOAuthUser()
        }

func registerOAuthUser() {
//do REST stuff here
doLogin()

}

func doLogin() {
//REST Login
saveAccessToken
hideLoadingOverlay()
performSegue

}
```

So basically now everytime the user enters my App - the creation REST call will be fired...

How can I prevent this, keeping in mind that the user will fire a chained up login call.(see pseudo Code above)

In the end the user should basically have received an account that is the same like if you would have taken the manual registration steps and autologin just with NSUserCredentials and an access token.

Comment: let me try to understand here. Your facebook login works - you're able to login through facebook, but you actually want to create an account for the user? Is this correct? I have implemented a facebook login in one of my projects but have implemented the facebook login a bit different than you. I can give you send you the documentation I used.

Comment: Yep exactly, I only use FB Login for "legitimation" - to create a real user account for the REST Service. I would love to study example implementations like yours. :)

Comment: got it. I can share that with you tonight when i get home.

Comment: Are you using Parse as your backend?

Comment: nope, i use a custom REST api - but I am pretty sure parse wont have such unusual components ^^